# Wsservice fails while attempting to fix Windows Store 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, powershell, services, windows-services

My Metro Apps are not loading. They return:

```
This App can't run
```

Using this command in Powershell:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\AppxManifest.xml
```

Returns:

```
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered.
error 0xC0020017: windows.licensing failed to start WSService. Try again and contact the package publisher if the
problem persists.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 8609ca17-4097-0001-4bca-09869740d001 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 8609ca17-4097-0001-4bca-09869740d001
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPan ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\WINDOWS\Imme...ppxManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

Wsservice appears stopped with Startup type set to Manual.

Atempting a restart returns:

```
Windows could not start the Windows Store Service (WSService) service on Local Computer.

Error 1083: The executable program that this service is configured to run in does not implement the service.
```

[image]

What's happening?

Comment: Seems like the service may be corrupted. Have you run a used [SFC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) to check for corrupted/missing system files yet?

Comment: Yes SFC does not find corrupt files.

Comment: try all steps from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked besides refreshing or re-installing Windows was upgrading to Windows 10 Technical Preview ([January build 9926](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso)).

It fixed Windows Store, PC Settings and kept programs and settings intact. It does share some minor issues. However as for today it works better without the constant Wsservice errors that 8.1 had.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Start-Service WSService & powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\AppxManifest.xml
```

If that fails try calling WSService before starting the service

```
C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceAndNoImpersonation & powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Start-Service WSService & powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\AppxManifest.xml
```

Comment: This error appears: The ampersand (&) character is not allowed.

Comment: My apologies should have asked before answering: How are you running the commands; are you running from Powershell or command prompt? The above should work if you run from command prompt. If you're running from Powershell substitute the ampersand's (&) with semicolons (;) .

Comment: Thank you, both lines fail in Safe Mode with this: `windows.licensing failed to start WSService`, I will try now in a normal boot.

Comment: Same results on normal boot.

Comment: Are you running as an administrator? Can you confirm "RPC Endpoint Mapper" and "DCOM Server Process Launcher" are running?

Comment: Yes, launched cmd as admin, both services you mentioned are running with "automatic" startup.

Comment: Please see the full list of [running services here](http://i.imgur.com/CF0Rk29.png).